# Is a listener destroyed when the view is scrolled off the screen?

Tags: android, listener

Is a listener, for example the TextWatcher on the EditText, destroyed or removed when the view is scrolled off the screen. For example, I have a ListView where there are a few EditTexts in each ListView item. When the item is scrolled back onto the screen is it necessary to add a new listener to the EditText?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Listener is attached to the `EditText` so if the `EditText` is not destroyed neither the Listener attached to it.

Answer (score 0):

ListView will destroy invisible item view when we scroll the list, so the view such as EditText also wil be released automatically.

So it's necessary to re-set the listener.

Comment: I think you are correct. However, the item view will not be destroyed if you are using a ViewHolder like in my case.